# Check if property and privacy can be modified Sharepoint Online 2013 (O365)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

I have an application that work with user profile properties, but some of these properties cannot be modified (example: Name) on my O365 Profile (read only).

Has any way to get if the property and property privacy can be changed?

My application is a Provider-Hosted App using C#.

I'm using UserProfileService.asmx for update purpose, i searched and don't found any method to return this values in this service.

Can someone tell me if it is possible?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured it out,

Use the following code to access all information about user profile properties:
var propertiesInfos = _userProfileService.GetUserProfileSchema();